# Terraform > ipv6_address_count: "" => "0" (forces new resource)

Tags: terraform

I'm using the Terraform ec2 module from:

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws/1.5.0?tab=inputs

but get this when doing a plan:

```
    ipv6_address_count:                "" => "0" (forces new resource)
```

This is an optional parameter and I don't currently (or want to) have an IPv6 address.

Any way round this?

Comment: Why would you use that module over a straight `aws_instance` resource? It doesn't really add anything, doesn't make any sensible decisions for you and doesn't abstract anything at all. It seems completely pointless to me.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I agree with your point!