# AWS on Terraform - How to avoid 'forces new resource'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform to launch my cloud environments.

It seems that even minor configuration change affects many of the resources behind the scenes.

For example, In cases where I create AWS instances - a small change will lead to auto-generation of all the instances:

```
-/+ aws_instance.DC (new resource required)
      id:   "i-075deb0aaa57c2d" => <computed> (forces new resource) <----- How can we avoid that?
      ami:  "ami-01e306baaaa0a6f65" => "ami-01e306baaaa0a6f65"
      arn:  "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:857671114786:instance/i-075deb0aaa57c2d" => <computed>
      associate_public_ip_address: "false" => <computed>
      availability_zone: "ap-southeast-2a" => <computed>
      .
      .
```

My question is related specifically to AWS as the provider: 
**How can we avoid the destruction/creation of resources each time?**

Maybe a relevant flag in Terraform?

---

Related threads:

[Terraform > ipv6_address_count: "" => "0" (forces new resource)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874984/terraform-ipv6-address-count-0-forces-new-resource?rq=1)

[terraform > forces new resource on security group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496944/terraform-forces-new-resource-on-security-group)

---

**Edit:**

Diving inside the *plan* output it seems that there was a change in one of the resources:

```
  security_groups.#: "0" => "1" (forces new resource)
  security_groups.837544107: "" => "sg-0892062659392afa9" (forces new resource)
```

Question is still relevant from the perspective of how to avoid the re-creation.

Comment: The ID change is a consequence of replacing the resource. There should be another attribute there marked `forces new resource`.

Comment: In general the best way to control this is using the `lifecycle` block to specify attributes that you do not want to force a new resource.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian I found this: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/zero-downtime-updates-with-terraform/. If you want to shed some light on this it will be great (:

Comment: As @Adrian mentions you need to show the full plan output for that resource to show _why_ Terraform needs to replace the resource instead of modify it in place. Normally this is just down to the API not allowing that resource to be modified in that way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Terraform resources only force a new resource if there's no clear upgrade path when modifying a resource to match the new configuration. This is done at the provider level by setting the `ForceNew: true` flag on the parameter.

An example is shown with the [`ami` parameter on the `aws_instance` resource](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/a15140e1184d201c9cf4cfe46f154a48c4a08958/aws/resource_aws_instance.go#L45-L49):

```golang
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "ami": {
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
                ForceNew: true,
            },
```

This tells Terraform that if the `ami` parameter is changed then it shouldn't attempt to perform an update but instead destroy the resource and create a new one.

You can override the destroy then create behaviour with the [`create_before_destroy` lifecycle configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#create_before_destroy) block:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

In the event you changed the `ami` or some other parameter that can't be updated then Terraform would then create a new instance and then destroy the old one.

How you handle zero downtime upgrades of resources can be tricky and is largely determined on what the resource is and how you handle it. There's some more information about that in the [official blog](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/zero-downtime-updates-with-terraform/).

---

In your very specific use case with it being the `security_groups` that has changed this is mentioned on the [`aws_instance` resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html):

> NOTE: If you are creating Instances in a VPC, use vpc_security_group_ids instead.

This is because Terraform's AWS provider and the EC2 API that Terraform is using is backwards compatible with old EC2 Classic AWS accounts that predate VPCs. With those accounts you could create instances outside of VPCs but you couldn't change the security groups of the instance after it was created. If you wanted to change ingress/egress for the instance you needed to work within the group(s) you had attached to the instance already. With VPC based instances AWS allowed users to modify instance security groups without replacing the instance and so exposed a different way of specifying this in the API.

If you move to using `vpc_security_group_ids` instead of `security_groups` then you will be able to modify these without replacing your instances.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue I have replaced `security_groups` with `vpc_security_group_ids`
and the issue is resolved.

Comment: thank you @Rajeshwar you saved my instance from destruction ^^