# How to upgrade AWS MQ minor version in terraform in a non destructive manner

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have been playing around with using the terraform aws provider to create managed services such as Amazon MQ. I found this worked nicely overall but when testing changing the minor version (5.15.9 -> 5.15.10) this is a destructive process which would result in data loss if this was being performed on a live service.

I have read the documentation for the provisioner and did not any further config that would allow this to happen without destroying and recreating the broker(s). The only option I could see would be to manually update via AWS directly or allow minor updates to happen automatically.

Any feedback on if this can be done via Terraform? Otherwise I would imagine the best process might be some automation or manual pipeline using the AWS CLI to do upgrades but then the terraform state will be stale I would presume.

Edit:

See terraform for creating the broker below, I have removed content related to secret manager, security groups, subnets etc as it seemed to add bulk and not be related to the issue directly.

```
resource "aws_mq_broker" "broker" {
  broker_name                = "${var.env}_${var.team}_broker"
  engine_type                = "ActiveMQ"
  engine_version             = "5.15.9"
  deployment_mode            = "${lookup(var.team_env_config, "${var.env}_${var.team}_deployment_mode")}"
  host_instance_type         = "${lookup(var.team_env_config, "${var.env}_${var.team}_instance_type")}"
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = false
}
```

When testing the upgrade I just changed 5.15.9 -> 5.15.10

The output is as follows:

```
      deployment_mode:                 "SINGLE_INSTANCE" => "SINGLE_INSTANCE"
      engine_type:                     "ActiveMQ" => "ActiveMQ"
      engine_version:                  "5.15.9" => "5.15.10" (forces new resource)
```

That is just a snipped but as you can see the engine version change forces a new resource.

Comment: Can you post your tf files?

Comment: Good point @RodrigoM, I have added the terraform to the original post. I did take out unrelated stuff such as secret manager, subnets etc as it added a lot of bulk. It is pretty simple and to try the upgrade I only changed the engine version.

Comment: I just saw this related question which has a useful answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59309494/11050340

I do not understand at this point why a minor engine version change would not have an upgrade path so will leave this open for the moment and in the meantime take some time to go over that answer in more detail to see if there is a better way for me to upgrade with the create_before_destroy flag and preserve the underlying data.

Comment: There's an [issue on the AWS provider issue tracker](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11827) about this already and asking as a feature request. It wasn't possible before because when the `aws_mq_broker` resource was added there wasn't an option for setting the engine version in an update because AWS only supported one engine version and didn't provide an API to update in place. This isn't a lot of work to fix but does need doing and then reviewing an merging.

Comment: If you've ever contributed to a Terraform provider before you could do the work in a small amount of time and maintain your fork until it's merged. If that's not an option then you might just want to follow that issue and in the meanwhile make the change outside of Terraform and allow the refresh to update your state to match the configuration.

Comment: In your case, running it with `create_before_destroy` for this would create a new MQ broker without any data and then destroy the old one that contains data so would be a bad idea. `create_before_destroy` is only really useful for stateless things or at least where the state is not being destroyed (eg an instance that then attaches a separate EBS volume etc).

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR, that is really helpful and informative. I've not contributed to a terraform provider before but I am interested in that so will at least have a look into how that all hangs together :).